# Changing name of files with zipfile python

Tags: python

I want to change the name of the file I am extracting to something new:

```
i = 0
for file in zip_file.namelist():
     path = 'C:\test\object'
     zip_file.extract(file, path)  #Change name here of file
     i+=1
```

Is it possible to change the name of `file` to something like `str(i)+'_'+'file'`? I know I can use `shutil.move()`, but I want to maintain my style, if possible.

Comment: alternatively `'{0}_{1}'.format(i, file)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the file directly at the right location by using a file object through the open method of the zip_file object.

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('toto.zip')
target_path = 'C:\test\object'

for i, filename in enumerate(zip_file.namelist()):
    target = os.path.join(target_path, "%05d_%s" % (i, filename))
    file_obj = open(target, 'wb')
    try:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zip_file.open(filename, 'r'), file_obj)
    finally:
        file_obj.close()
```

By the way, you should avoid using local variables named "file" since it's a built-in type.